# How to bind more than one DataSet column value to a GroupStyle TextBlock

Tags: wpf, dataset, visual-studio-2019, textblock, groupstyle

I have the following DataSet with the "PART" DataTable Column bound as the PropertyGroupDescription. I also want to bind the "DESCRIPTION" Column, but without biding it to the PropertyGroupDescription, because that would effect the grouping.

What I get right now:

```
ID | NAME
PART: 1
1  | AAA
2  | BBB
PART: 2
3  | CCC
PART: 3
4  | DDD
5  | EEE
```

What I want to get:

```
ID | NAME
PART: 1, DESCRIPTION: ATLANTA
1  | AAA
2  | BBB
PART: 2, DESCRIPTION: NEW YORK
3  | CCC
PART: 3, DESCRIPTION: BOSTON
4  | DDD
5  | EEE
```

As all of the rows with the same Part number share the same Description.

Current Code:

CS:

```
public DataTable DataGridParts;
readonly CollectionViewSource mycollection;

public void FillDataGridParts()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PARTS] WHERE [STA_SID] = @StaSid AND [OWNER] LIKE @Search COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI ORDER BY LEN ([PART]), [PART] ASC, [DESCRIPTION] DESC, [SHARE] DESC",
        Connection = SQLConnection.con
    };
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaSid", GlobalStrings.building_sta_sid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", '%' + textbox_search_part.Text + '%');

    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataGridParts.Clear();
    da.Fill(DataGridParts);
    datagrid_parts.ItemsSource = DataGridParts.DefaultView;
    mycollection.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
    mycollection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("PART"));
    datagrid_parts.ItemsSource = mycollection.View;
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;;
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Height="20" Padding="0,3,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Background="#e4e4e4">
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}PART: {0}, DESCRIPTION: {1}">
                                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                                            <Binding Path="???" /> //NO IDEA HOW TO BIND HERE
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Binding Path="Items[0].DESCRIPTION" />` should work assuming that all rows with the same Part share the same Description and that there is a column named "DESCRIPTION" in the `DataTable`.

Comment: I know it is against the rules, but I love you.